# Java creating program that validates password

Tags: java

I have to write password validation program.

You will have these methods:

main(String[]): calls getValidPassword

getValidPassword(): checks that the password has all criteria and prints the confirmation statement if valid, otherwise prints the invalid statement and accepts a new password

checkLength(String): returns true if the password String fits the length criteria, otherwise returns false

checkUpperCase(String): returns true if the password String has the enough uppercase letters, otherwise returns false

checkLowerCase(String): returns true if the password String has the enough lowercase letters, otherwise returns false

checkNumbers(String): returns true if the password String has the enough numbers, otherwise returns false

The above list is in the format:

methodName(listOfParameterTypes): functionality and return values if any
Please be sure to keep the names of methods strictly as given for this lab.

- **This is my code. My problem is case when password is wrong. How
  to make it get another input... until user Enters correct password which satisfies the list.**

enter code here

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordValidator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

      String password=sc.nextLine();
      getValidPassword(password);

   }

   public static void getValidPassword(String password) {

      boolean valid;

      if ( checkLength(password) && checkUpperCase(password) && checkLowerCase

(password) && checkNumbers(password) ) {
         System.out.print("Password accepted");
         valid=true;
      }
      else {
         System.out.print("Invalid password, try again");
         valid=false;

      }

   }


   //checks PASSWORDS length
   public static boolean checkLength(String password) {
      boolean length;

      if (password.length() >= 8 ) {
         length=true;
      }
      else {
         length=false;
      }

      return length;

   }//finish length check

   //checks uppercase
   public static boolean checkUpperCase(String password) {
      int j=0;
      boolean upper;

      //count uppercases
      String word=password.toUpperCase();
      for (int i=0; i<password.length(); ++i) {
         if (password.charAt(i)==word.charAt(i)) {
            ++j;
         }
         else {

                j=j;
             }
          }

          if (j>=2) {
             upper=true;
          }
          else {
             upper=false;
          }

          return upper;

       }//finish uppercase check

       //checks lowercase
          public static boolean checkLowerCase(String password) {
          int j=0;
          String word=password.toLowerCase();
          boolean low;
          //count lower cases
          for (int i=0; i<password.length(); ++i) {
             if (password.charAt(i)==word.charAt(i)) {
                ++j;
             }
             else {
                j=j;
             }
          }

          if (j>=1) {
             low=true;
          }
          else {
             low=false;
          }

          return low;   
       }//finish lowercase

       //check numbers
       public static boolean checkNumbers(String password) {
          int j=0;
          boolean num;

          for (int i=0; i<password.length(); ++i) {
             if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
                ++j;
             }
             else {
                j=j;
             }
          }

             if (j>=2) {
                num=true;
             }
             else {
                num=false;
             }



       return num;
       }//finish numbers





    }
```

Comment: You want to read about **while** loops. And please note: this is not a free tutor service where people *teach* you super basic stuff. You are expected to do serious research prior posting questions here to avoid asking things that are documented in any good book or tutorial ... over and over again.

Comment: Stop writing and saying "so" and "basically" - useless filler words.  Do yourself a favor and start with a method isValid that takes in a String and returns a boolean.  Test it until it's perfect and then worry about user interaction and I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate out all that IO and concentrate on the method.

```
public class PasswordValidator {

    public static boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        // add logic and rules here
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Test it using JUnit, not command line input.

```
public class PasswordValidatorTest {
    @Test
    public void testIsValidPassword_Success() {
        // setup
        // exercise
        // assert
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidPassword_Failure() {
        // setup
        // exercise
        // assert
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordValidator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

      String password=sc.nextLine();
      while(getValidPassword(password))
      {
            System.out.println("Wrong Password!! Try Again");
      }
   }

   public static boolean getValidPassword(String password) {

      boolean valid;

      if ( checkLength(password) && checkUpperCase(password) && checkLowerCase(password) && checkNumbers(password) ) {
         System.out.print("Password accepted");
         valid=true;
      }
      else {
         System.out.print("Invalid password, try again");
         valid=false;
        }
        return valid;
   }
    //checks PASSWORDS length
   public static boolean checkLength(String password) {
      boolean length;

      if (password.length() >= 8 ) {
         length=true;
      }
      else {
         length=false;
      }

      return length;

   }//finish length check

   //checks uppercase
   public static boolean checkUpperCase(String password) {
      int j=0;
      boolean upper;

      //count uppercases
      String word=password.toUpperCase();
      for (int i=0; i<password.length(); ++i) {
         if (password.charAt(i)==word.charAt(i)) {
            ++j;
         }
         else {

                j=j;
             }
          }

          if (j>=2) {
             upper=true;
          }
          else {
             upper=false;
          }

          return upper;

       }//finish uppercase check

       //checks lowercase
          public static boolean checkLowerCase(String password) {
          int j=0;
          String word=password.toLowerCase();
          boolean low;
          //count lower cases
          for (int i=0; i<password.length(); ++i) {
             if (password.charAt(i)==word.charAt(i)) {
                ++j;
             }
             else {
                j=j;
             }
          }

          if (j>=1) {
             low=true;
          }
          else {
             low=false;
          }

          return low;   
       }//finish lowercase

       //check numbers
       public static boolean checkNumbers(String password) {
          int j=0;
          boolean num;

          for (int i=0; i<password.length(); ++i) {
             if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
                ++j;
             }
             else {
                j=j;
             }
          }

             if (j>=2) {
                num=true;
             }
             else {
                num=false;
             }
       return num;
       }//finish numbers
    }
```